# How to reset BX slider numbering on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

What I have are 2 different buttons for 1 slider (because the content of the slider will be dynamic). My issue is that since the slider is triggered using the same class, when I click on the second button, the slider's position is retained. What I'd like to happen is for the slider to restart to slide 1 whenever I click the button.

```
$(".modal-close").on('click', function() {
   $(".modal1").hide();
});
```

```js
$(".modal1").hide();

$(".sampleclick").on('click', function() {
    $(".modal1").show();
     $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: false,
    controls: false,
    pager: true
  });
});

$(".modal-close").on('click', function() {
   $(".modal1").hide();
});

/* SLIDER */

$(document).ready(function(){

 


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal1" style="background: #CCC; width: 1000px;height 1000px; position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 0px;">

              <ul class="bxslider">
                <li class="">

                    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_gTJMEP-c2fo/SLffF6y0iTI/AAAAAAAAEAc/aGZ3z7Gc4ac/s640/Cat+Kiss+4.jpg">
                    <br>
                    <p><a class="modal-close">CLOSE</a></p>
                    
                </li>
                <li class="">

                    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/62/26/9c/62269c9bb6312f35247579865d895a33.jpg"><br>
                    <p><a class="modal-close">CLOSE</a></p>

                </li>
                <li class="">
                

                    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d4/d2/3f/d4d23fa5509136af2a51c69b6af58839.jpg">
                    <br>
                    <p>
                    
                    <a class="modal-close">CLOSE</a></p>

                </li>
              </ul>
        
            </div>

            <a class="sampleclick">BUTTON 1</a>
            
            <a class="sampleclick">BUTTON 2</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/iamacatperson/5s6nowaq/2/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
auto: false,
controls: false,
pager: true
});


$(".sampleclick").on('click', function() {
$(".modal1").show();

slider.reloadSlider();

});

$(".modal-close").on('click', function() {
$(".modal1").hide();
});
```